# Force binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, data-binding

I'm writing tests which will check correctness of `Binding` elements specified in XAML. They work so far, the only issue is that I do not know how to correctly force databinding to happen. Surprisingly it is not enough to simply set something in `DataContext`, binding won't happen until you show your control/window. Please not that I'm writing 'unit'-tests and I'd like to avoid showing any windows.

Take a look at following code:

```
// This is main class in console application where I have all WPF references added
public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        var view = new Window();
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(view, Window.TitleProperty, new Binding("Length"));
        view.DataContext = new int[5];
        //view.Show(); view.Close(); // <-- this is the code I'm trying not to write
        Console.WriteLine(view.Title);
    }
}
```

Here I'm creating a Window and putting an array as `DataContext` to that window. I'm binding `Window.Title` to `Array.Length` so I expect to see number `5` printed in console. But until I `Show` window (commented line) I will get empty string. If I uncomment that line then I will receive desired `5` in console output.

Is there any way I can make binding happen without showing a window? It is pretty annoying to look at ~20 windows while launching tests.

P.S.: I know I can make windows more transparent and etc, but I'm looking for more elegant solution.

**UPDATE** Code above is simplified version of what I really have. In real code I receive a `View` (some `UIElement` with bindings) and `object ViewModel`. I do not know which exactly binding there were set on `View`, but I still want all of them to be initialized.

**UPDATE 2**: Answering to the questions regarding what I test and I why. I do not intend to test that classes like `Binding`, `BindingBase`, etc are working as expected, I assume they are working. I'm trying to test that in all my XAML files I have written bindings correctly. Because bindings are stringly typed things, they are not verified during compilation and by default they cause only errors in output window, which I'm missing occasionally. So if we take my example from above and if we will made a typo there in binding: `{Binding Lengthhh}` then my tests will notify you that there is no property with name `Lengthhh` available for binding. So I have around 100 XAML files and for each XAML I have a test (3-5 lines of code) and after launching my tests I know **for sure** that there are no binding errors in my solution.

Comment: Have you tried calling view.UpdateLayout() or view.InvalidateVisual()?

Comment: @Aaron, tried right now, didn't help.

Comment: @Snowbear Have you tried these varying approaches in a standard WPF application?

Comment: @Snowbear Testing a View is notoriously difficult. Why not create an instance of the View in xUnit or whatever testing framework you are using and verify the controls have the expected values based on setting the DataContext to a given ViewModel? Stating unit tests are similar to a console application doesn't mean anything...you are testing the View regardless of the testing framework you are using.

Comment: @Snowbear If you are not testing that the value within the binding is accurate then your test is narrow and you are now attempting to test the .NET FW, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Snowbear Just because a binding works doesn't mean the value is correct. You are simply making certain a property exists on your ViewModel. If that has value to you then go for it; it appears to be a waste of time IMHO.

Comment: I think the question's title could use a revision to something like "How can I unit-test my WPF-XAML bindings?" :-)

Comment: @Danny, No, the point is exactly in forcing binding. I know how to test bindings it (in more or less convinient way) but at the moment I have a place which I'd like to refactor - it is a place where I need to force a binding. At the moment I'm doing `window.Show` but I was hoping that somebody might suggest me a more suitable solution.

Answer (score 4):

The bindings are updated by the dispatcher with the DispatcherPriority.DataBind - so if you wait for a dummy task with SystemIdle priority you are sure that any pending databinding is done.

```
  try
  {
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new Action(() => { }));
  }
  catch
  {
    // Cannot perfom this while Dispatcher in suspended mode
  }
```

Comment: Yes, this helped

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to test correctness of your view, I suggest you test your view :-)

Why not run the UI from a unit test and write code that checks content of UI after changing data.

VS2010 does have GUI testing, or you could take a look at the code of tools such as Snoop.

---

Edit following comment:

If ALL you want to do is test a few simple bindings, try writing a static code test that runs as a post build event using reflection on view models and regular expressions on XAMLs. Add attributes on VM or use a config file so your test will know which view receives which View Model as DataContext. Compare property names and types in View Models with binding strings in View (automatically search XAML for these) and throw exception (thus failing build) if strings do not match.

If your bindings are more complex (converters, multibindings, ...) this may be a bit more complicated to implement.

Comment: The point is that I can do full view tests but this will take pretty much time for each view and these tests will require some time to be maintained. I'm trying to avoid that. I have tests which consist of 1 line per each view, I can add them instantly as soon as I add a view and interface of ViewModel and these tests cover around 90% of errors I do. That's enough for me, I don't want to spend 20 times more time to find only additional 5-8 % of bugs. Thanks for the idea about VS2010 testing, I implemented my solution when there was no vs2010 so I haven't looked at that yet. Will do.

Comment: binding a quite complex in that way that there are several places where I have nested bindings - these places will be complicated for 'regex' approach. But I think you gave me a good idea, but instead of regexes I'm thinking on traversing a visual tree. Also see my comment below the question. I'm still more qurious about how to `force bindings to happen`. I already have enough good ideas suggested here to improve my tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first set the DataContext and then do the Binding, e.g.:

```
view.DataContext = new int[5];
BindingOperations.SetBinding(view, Window.TitleProperty, new Binding("Length"));
```

I'm not sure if this is real solution for your general problem, but it works in this case.

Comment: It works, but I cannot do it in real code. In my real code (see my first update) I receive a `View` already with all bindings. Binding are created out of XAML and XAML is parsed as part of `InitializeComponents` which is called in constructor, so there is no way to get `View` before setting bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the `Window`'s bindings will run without calling `Show` or `ShowDialog`, because that is the only way it gets associated with the UI message loop/dispatcher.

Your best bet would be to set it to be as least visible as possible, potentially using an extension method to clean things up:

```
public static void PokeWindowDispatcher(this Window window)
{
    window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    window.Visibility = Visibility.None;

    using (var wait = new ManualResetEvent())
    {
        Action<object, RoutedEventArgs> loaded = (sender, e) => wait.Set();
        window.Loaded += loaded;
        try
        {
            window.Show();
            wait.WaitOne();
        }
        finally
        {
            window.Loaded -= loaded;
            window.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bindings can work without `Show`, you can check *Gimno's* approach. With his code `binding` do work, though I his solution is not suitable for me.

Comment: You might try pushing a new `DispatcherFrame` with `Dispatcher.PushFrame()`, but I don't believe if the `HWND` has not been made for your `Window` that anything will happen. Mulling on this some more I think in order to get the highest fidelity testing of your bindings you need the Window to run to complete loading such that any resources they rely on (static/dynamic) get loaded as well. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I guess I should clarify that I meant the *Window* is not likely to execute its own bindings without `Show` or `ShowDialog`. Through manual creation or frobbing you could get individual bindings to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and from sixlettervariables gave me an idea. It's very simple.
I am using WPF in WinForms application, so I use ElementHost control to host Wpf controls on WinForms control. To enforce WinForms control initialization you can just read value of Handle (which is actually Windows HWND) and this will force control to fully initialize itself including child ElementHost and all Wpf binding work.
I didn`t try to perform the same thing for pure Wpf control. But you can easily use ElementHost to initialize your Wpf controls like this:

```
var el = new ElementHost();
var p = new TextBlock();
p.DataContext = new { Data = "1234" };
p.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, "Data");
el.Child = p;
var t = el.Handle;
Debug.Assert(p.Text == "1234");
```

PS: Found, that everything work better, if you first set DataContext and only then force a Handle to be created (just like my example). But, I think, this is already the case for you, so should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it out tomorrow. But I think there is some misunderstanding here. I know how to force binding happen, but at the moment I'm looking for a more clean way than creating a separate window which I'm doing now. Your approach seems for me seems to be the same as creating new window. And comment regarding your PS: I've already commented it in *Gimno's* answer, I cannot set `DataContext` in advance.

Comment: yes, with my aproach you have to create a control, but you don`t have to show it. Actually, after I posted this answer, I have myself written a bunch of unit tests for Wpf views and everything works fine. As for setting DataContext. In your example you set DataContext in the test code. I mean, that you only should request ElementHost handle right after setting DataContext, instead of showing window. Once you do this, all binding work and update as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to use the IsDataBound

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.isdatabound.aspx

Also check this out:

System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper helper = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(view).EnsureHandle();

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.ensurehandle.aspx

My other question is why you trying to do a UNIT test on something that has been technically tested already? By the way I am not critising, just want to understand a little better.

Comment: Hi, how do you think `IsDataBound` will help me? I know that it wasn't bound, I need to force it. And no, `WindowInteropHelper` didn't help, binding wasn't populated. Regarding your last question, see my update #2 in the question itself, I do not try to test MS binding classes, I'm testing that my bindings in views are correct.

Comment: You have a good point there, so after a arduous research ( Just Kidding ), I did not find a definitive answer, but apparently there is no easy way of achiving this. Take a look at this.

http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/08/05/unit-testing-xaml-data-bindings-in-silverlight.aspx

Comment: Now on other hand you can change the way you are approaching the problem, so instead of assuming that you will type something right. Why don't you write a Metadata class for each of your ViewModels, with static classes, then when you bind you bind with that, so you know that its right as long as you typed it right on the metada class. Does that help?

Comment: well it is also an interesting idea but this will require adding one more class per each VM (T4 might help) which is too much for me at the moment. I'm kind of stopped refining the approach at the moment, but when I'll get back to it I will keep your idea in mind. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but maybe something like this will work?

```
view.GetBindingExpression(Window.TitleProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

Comment: This won't help because in real code I do not know which bindings were set on `View`, see my update